# How can I compare one string elements to array of strings elements?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, function

I have a function which compares 2 strings and prints out how many elements in common. My current code is:

```
public void StringCheck(String one, String two) { 

    String[] subStrings1 = one.split(", ");
    String[] subStrings2 = two.split(", ");

    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();

    for (String s : subStrings1) {
        set1.add(s);
    }
    for (String s : subStrings2) {
        set2.add(s);
    }
    set1.retainAll(set2);
    textView3.setText(set1.size() + "");
}
```

When I call the function like this: `StringCheck("1, 2, 3, 4, 5" , "1, 2, 3, 4 ,5");` it prints out `5` in my android screen.

But I actually want to compare my first string to another strings. For example, I want to give one string and one string array as parameters and see how many elements in common.
Assume that my first string is: `"1, 2, 3, 4, 5"` I want to compare this one to others. Let's say,
second one `"2, 3, 4, 5, 6"`
third one `"3, 4, 5, 6, 7"`

I want the output be like:

`Result 1: 4 Result 2: 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code with input: `StringCheck("1, 2, 3, 4, 5" , new String[]{"1, 5","1, 2, 3, 4, 5","7"});`

```
 public static void StringCheck(String one, String []two){
    String[] numbersOne = one.split(", ");//1 2 3 4 5
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < two.length; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        String [] numbersTwo = two[i].split(", ");//2 3 4 5 6
        for (int j = 0; j < numbersTwo.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < numbersOne.length; k++) {
                if(numbersTwo[j].equals(numbersOne[k])){
                    counter++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        result+="Result "+(i+1)+":"+counter+" ";
    }
        textView3.setText(result); 
}
```

The output will be: `Result 1:2 Result 2:5 Result 3:0`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit crude but this should work:

```
public void StringCheck(String one, String[] two) { 
    String result = "";

    String[] subStrings1 = one.split(", ");
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();

    // Add all the targets to a set
    for(String s: subStrings1)
    {
        set1.add(s);
    }

    // For each of the input strings in the array
    for(int i = 0; i < two.length; ++i)
    {
        // Keep track of the total, and split based on the comma
        int total = 0;
        String[] subStrings2 = two[i].split(", ");

        // For each of the substrings
        for(String s2: subStrings2)
        {
            // If the set contains that substring, increment
            if(set1.contains(s2))
            {
                ++total;
            }
        }

        // Format result string
        result += "Result " + (i+1) + ":" + total + " ";            
    }

    //Set the text view
    textView3.setText(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code works for one comparison. 
Why not simply extract the part that count the number of intersection  into a method and invoke it for each comparison that you want to perform ?

```
public int countNbIntersection(String one, String two) { 

    String[] subStrings1 = one.split(", ");
    String[] subStrings2 = two.split(", ");

    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();

    for (String s : subStrings1) {
        set1.add(s);
    }
    for (String s : subStrings2) {
        set2.add(s);
    }
    set1.retainAll(set2);
    return set1.size();
}
```

You can so invoke it and produce the expected message :

```
String reference = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
String other = "2, 3, 4, 5, 6";
String other2 = "3, 4, 5, 6, 7";

String firstCount = "Result 1 " + countNbIntersection(reference, other);
String secondCount = "Result 2 " +countNbIntersection(reference, other2);
String msg = firstCount  +  " " + secondCount;
```